# Alternate of UpsetR graph or visualizing the intersection of many variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on patients data and I have around 77 variables of different medications which shows if a patient is on that medication or not. I want to have a look visually that how the intersection of different medication by patients will look like. I used upsetR but visually that works up to 16 variables perfectly. If I am including all my variables then the graph looks very jumbled and nothing could be read and understand from the graph. Is there any alternative way to visualize such intersect data other than UpsetR ? Below is the example of my data.

```
my_dataframe <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0, 1), 637599 * 77, replace = TRUE), ncol = 77))
colnames(my_dataframe) <- paste0("Ind_", 1:77)

library(UpSetR)
upset(my_dataframe, nsets = 77)
```

Below are the examples and difference of both graphs.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[ComplexUpset](https://krassowski.github.io/complex-upset/articles/Examples_R.html) has examples visualising a focused set of intersections, e.g. with at least n members.

If the requirement is to see everything, then a possible approach may be to review them as a sorted (long) table of intersections, perhaps printed with the gt package.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_dataframe <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0, 1), 1024 * 10, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10))
colnames(my_dataframe) <- paste0("Ind_", 1:10)
  
my_dataframe |> 
  mutate(row = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(-row) |> 
  mutate(value = if_else(value == 1, name, NA)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) |> 
  unite(col = intersect, -row, sep = " | ", na.rm = TRUE) |>
  count(intersect, sort = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 644 × 2
#>    intersect                                                  n
#>    <chr>                                                  <int>
#>  1 Ind_3 | Ind_4 | Ind_7 | Ind_10                             7
#>  2 Ind_1 | Ind_2 | Ind_4 | Ind_6 | Ind_7 | Ind_10             6
#>  3 Ind_3 | Ind_4 | Ind_5 | Ind_6 | Ind_8 | Ind_9 | Ind_10     5
#>  4 Ind_1 | Ind_2 | Ind_3 | Ind_4 | Ind_5 | Ind_7 | Ind_9      4
#>  5 Ind_1 | Ind_2 | Ind_3 | Ind_4 | Ind_8 | Ind_10             4
#>  6 Ind_1 | Ind_2 | Ind_3 | Ind_5 | Ind_8 | Ind_9              4
#>  7 Ind_1 | Ind_2 | Ind_7 | Ind_9 | Ind_10                     4
#>  8 Ind_1 | Ind_3 | Ind_4 | Ind_5 | Ind_7 | Ind_8 | Ind_10     4
#>  9 Ind_1 | Ind_3 | Ind_5 | Ind_6 | Ind_7 | Ind_8 | Ind_9      4
#> 10 Ind_1 | Ind_3 | Ind_6 | Ind_7 | Ind_9                      4
#> # ℹ 634 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>